# Best way to sum group value_counts in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my DataFrame:

```
id b1 b2 b3 c
-------------
 1 aa bb cc a
 2 ac bc cd b
 3 ac ad cc a
 4 ad cd ae b
```

b1 b2 and b3 is 3 cols have the same meaning. And now I want to group the data by col `c` and calculate the value_counts() of the words in b1 b2 and b3. Here is my code:

```
grp = df.groupby('c')
vc1 = grp['b1'].value_counts()
vc2 = grp['b2'].value_counts()
vc3 = grp['b3'].value_counts()

sum([vc1, vc2, vc3])
```

But then there is a lot of NA in the result. How can I set the default value as 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pretty efficient method

groupby the 'c' column, and consider all the columns that you want passed to the `apply` EXCEPT for c (this is what `df.columns-['c']` does, as normally the grouping column IS passed to the apply.

then simply `value_counts` on all of the data (the `ravel` flattens the 2-d to a 1-d) as you want to total anyhow.

```
In [92]: df.groupby('c')[df.columns - ['c']].apply(lambda x: x.unstack().value_counts())
Out[92]: 
c    
a  cc    2
   bb    1
   ad    1
   ac    1
   aa    1
b  cd    2
   ad    1
   ae    1
   ac    1
   bc    1
dtype: int64
```

If you want as columns

```
In [97]: df.groupby('c')[df.columns - ['c']].apply(lambda x: x.unstack().value_counts()).unstack().T.fillna(0)
Out[97]: 
c   a  b
aa  1  0
ac  1  1
ad  1  1
ae  0  1
bb  1  0
bc  0  1
cc  2  0
cd  0  2
```

Comment: +1 just for `df.columns - ['c']`; didn't know that worked!  BTW, I think you can condense your `lambda` to `lambda x: x.unstack().value_counts())`, and it might be worth mentioning you'd need to get rid of any extraneous columns (if `id` is a column and not an index.)

Comment: updated for the unstack; good thinking! I think need a way exclude the grouped column (now you can do ``as_index=False`` but that actually drops them, maybe ``as_index='exclude'`` might work)....

Comment: api issue for this type of exclusion: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7155

Comment: I tried, it does not work...The demo works well but I have to use some ugly way to make it done.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I propose based on pandas function `groupby`, `get_group`, `value_counts`, `add`.

```
import pandas as pd
# Creation of the dataframe example
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'b1':['aa','ac','ac','ad'],\
                             'b2':['bb','bc','ad','cd'],\
                             'b3':['cc','cd','cc','ae'],\
                             'c' :['a','b','a','b']})
# Group data wrt column c
grp = df.groupby('c')
# Create empty dataframe that will hold results
dfc = pd.DataFrame()
# Iterate over all groups
for g in grp.groups:
    # Select the current group
    cg = grp.get_group(g)
    # Iterate over all columns to be counted
    for c in ['b1','b2','b3']:
        # Perform all value_counts and
        # add result to the correct column in result dataframe
        dfc = dfc.add(pd.DataFrame({g:cg[c].value_counts()}),fill_value=0)
# Replace all Nan with 0
dfc.fillna(0, inplace = True)
```

Result will look like this

```
    a  b
aa  1  0
ac  1  1
ad  1  1
ae  0  1
bb  1  0
bc  0  1
cc  2  0
cd  0  2
```

Comment: really liked this solution